# How can use single UIcustomviewCell xib for more than one TableView view Controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have two tableview controllers and one `UITableviewCell xib`, I want to use this `UITableViewCell`
in both View Controllers. How can it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just define your common **UITableviewCell** in both tableview controller's **cellForRowAtIndexPath** delegate methods. See the below code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CommonCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier ];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *cells = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CommonCell" owner:nil options:nil];
        for (id eachObject in cells) {
            if ([eachObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
                cell = eachObject;
                break;
            }
        }


    }


    return cell;
}
```